# in-class in-line non-static field initialization + object pool -> decrease maintainability/readability

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, pool, class-members

To improve performance when creating & destroying object, pooling is a possibility.

In some situation, I don't want to go into low-level techniques like custom allocator or `char[]`.
Another way is to create **object pool**.
However, this technique doesn't go well with in-class field (inline) initialization.

At first, I didn't think this is a problem at all.
However, the pattern keeps re-appear hundred times, and I think I should have some counter-measure.

### Example

Assume that the first version of my program looks like this:-

```
class Particle{
    int lifeTime=100;  //<-- inline initialization
    //.... some function that modify "lifeTIme"
};
int main(){
    auto p1=new Particle();
    delete p1;
    //... many particle created & deleted randomly ...
};
```

After the adopt of object pool, my program can be:-

```
class Particle{
    int lifeTime=100;   //<---- maintainability issue
    void reset(){
        lifeTime=100;   //<---- maintainability issue
    }
};
int main(){
    auto* p1=pool.create(); 
    //.... "Particle::reset()" have to be called somewhere.
};
```

The duplicating code causes some maintainability issue.

### Question

How to adopt object-pool to an existing object that has inline-field-initialization without sacrificing code-maintainability and readability?

### My current workaround

I usually let the constructor call `reset()`.

```
class Particle{
    int lifeTime;  
    public: Particle(){ 
        reset();    //<---- call it here, or "pool" call it
    }
    void reset(){
        lifeTime=100;  
    }
};
```

**Disadvantage:**  It reduces code-readability comparing to the old inline-initialization:-

```
int lifeTime=100;
```

Sorry if it is too beginner question, I am new to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a usual usecase for [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
class Base {
    static constexpr int lifespan = 100;
    int lifetime = lifespan;

public:
    void reset() noexcept { lifetime = lifespan; }
}

struct Deleter {
    void operator ()(Base* const b) const {
        b->reset();
    }
};

struct Particle : Base {
    // ...
};

struct Pool {
    std::unique_ptr<Particle, Deleter> create() {
        // ...
    }
}

int main() {
    // ...
    auto p1 = pool.create();
}
```

Comment: I love "static constexpr int lifespan = 100;".

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this really depends on the combination of

- Why do you need to pool objects?
- Why do objects need to have a default `lifeTime` of `100`?
- Why do objects need to change their `lifeTime`?
- Why do existing objects obtained from the pool need to have their `lifeTime` reset to `100`.

You have partially answered the first, although I'll bet your stated goal of improving performance is not based on anything other than "you think you need to improve performance".    Really, such a goal should be based on measured performance being insufficient, otherwise it is no more than premature optimisation.

In any event, if I assume for sake of discussion that all of my questions above have good answers, I would do the following;

```
class Particle
{   
   public:

      // member functions that provide functions used by `main()`.

   private:     // note all the members below are private

       Particle();
       void reset()
       {
            lifeTime=100;
       };

       friend class Pool;
   };

   class Pool
   {
        public:

             Particle *create()
             {
                   Particle *p;

                    // obtain an object for p to point at
                    //    that may mean release it from some "pool" or creating a new one

                    p->reset();
                    return p;
             };

             void give_back(Particle *&p)
             {
                  // move the value of p back into whatever the "pool" is

                  p = NULL;    //  so the caller has some indication it should not use the object
             };
   };

int main()
{
     // presumably pool is created somehow and visible here     

     auto* p1=pool.create(); 

     // do things with p1

     pool.give_back(p1);    // we're done with p1

     auto *p2 = pool.create();
      // p2 might or might not point at what was previously p1
}
```

Note that the value `100` only ever appears in the `reset()` function.

The reason for making constructors private and `Pool` a `friend` is to prevent accidental creation of new objects (i.e. to force use of the pool).

Optionally, making `Particle::reset()` be `public` allows `main()` to call `p1->reset()`, but that is not required.   However, all objects when obtained from the pool (whether created fresh or reused) will be reset.

I'd probably also make use of `std::unique_ptr<Particle>` so the lifetime of objects is properly managed, for example, if you forget to give the object back to the pool.    I'll leave implementing that sort of thing as an exercise.